# Etale cohomology in the $p$-adic setting

Tags: p-adic-numbers, etale-cohomology

Can we hope for application of Etale cohomology techniques in proving results concerning semialgebraic subsets of $\mathbb{Q}_p^n$?

Recall that semialgebraic subsets are obtained from $p$-adic algebraic varieties  using boolean connectives and coordinate projection.

The results I am interested in are a sort of algebraic topology over the $p$-adics. But of course one cannot use the standard topology on the $p$-adics since it is totally disconnected. So I hope to show for instance that a ball with one smaller ball removed cannot be diffeomorphic to a ball, etc .

Comment: Your question is a bit vague... What do you mean by semialgebraic subset ? What kind of results are you interested in ?

Comment: @François: I edited the question. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) A ball (of finite radius) is compact, and a punctured ball is not, so they cannot be diffeomorphic.

2) A theorem of Serre (*Topology*, 1965, vol. **3**, p. 409-412) classifies all compact $p$-adic manifolds.
The result is:

> a) Any such (non-empty) manifold is isomorphic to a finite disjoint union of balls.
>
> b) For positive integers $a$ and $b$, the union of $a$ balls is isomorphic to the union of $b$ ones if and only if $a\equiv b\pmod{p-1}$.

For example, the unit ball is isomorphic to the union of $p$ disjoint balls (the residue classes).

[Edit, 6/15/2012: I corrected and added the reference to Serre's paper.]

Comment: I know these results. Can we extend these to say that there is no diffeomorphism from $\mathbbQ_p^n$ onto $\mathbb{Q}_p^n \setminus B$ for $B$ a ball?

Comment: Aren't both of them countable infinite unions of disjoint balls?

Comment: What happens if you restrict to semialgebraic diffeomorphism?


Comment: For those interested, the reference for the Serre paper given here is not correct.  I believe the correct reference for this result is the paper "Classification des variétés analytiques p-adiques compactes" from Topology 3 (1965), pp. 409-412.

Comment: You're right.Sorry for the misprint. I correct it.
